# SaxonJS unusable with webpack

Tags: webpack, saxon, saxon-js

I'm running into an issue when trying to integrate `SaxonJS` into a larger web application using `webpack`. From what I can tell, `webpack` views `SaxonJS` as just another module, but `SaxonJS` is not structured as an `AMD` or `CommonJS` module. Instead, the `Big.js` (a `SaxonJS` dependency) hijacks the export. I believe that fixing Node.js support will also fix this issue.

```js
import * as SaxonJS from "./Saxon-JS/SaxonJS.js";
export class Transformer {

    public static transform(inputStr: string, sefFile: string, cb: Function) {
        // wrap the JSON in XML, as required by XSLT transform
        let wrappedJson = `<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">${inputStr}</root>`;
        SaxonJS.transform({
            sourceText: wrappedJson,
            stylesheetLocation: `xslt/${sefFile}`,
            initialTemplate: "start",
            destination: "application"
        }, cb);
    };
}
```

Please note this is a web scenario; SaxonJS is being invoked by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

it's always good to see how people are trying to use Saxon-JS. We at Saxonica would certainly be interested to hear more about what you are trying to do, and how. It is not too surprising that the integration you are attempting does not currently work. Saxon-JS 1 is not really built as a JS module (e.g. note that a copy of `Big.js` is contained inside `SaxonJS`, it is not a module dependency).

We are working hard on the next major release, Saxon-JS 2.0, which will include a version for Node.js (as you know, Saxon-JS 1 is for the browser only). We want to get the module packaging right this time so that JavaScript developers such as yourself can indeed integrate the `SaxonJS` module as you'd expect to. Your insights would be very welcome!

We have so far tended to focus on building stand alone web applications using XSLT and the IXSL extensions provided, but we do want to understand better how users can/would like to integrate Saxon-JS into larger existing applications. Please could you get in touch directly with more details of your use case? (e.g. see the Contacts section on the Saxonica website for the support email address.)