# Unable to use Saxon-JS 2 with Webpack

Tags: webpack, saxon, saxon-js

I've tried to use the latest version of saxon-js with webpack as a module bundler – but trying to build the bundle produces an error. Saxon-js was installed using `npm`.

I've used the following code to import saxon-js:

```
import * as SaxonJS from 'saxon-js';
```

as well as

```
import SaxonJS from 'saxon-js';
```

While trying to import saxon-js this way webpack produces the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/bastian/Documents/Coding-Projekte/newversioningmachine/node_modules/saxon-js'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./src/js/index.js 1:0-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js 4661:277-292
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/bastian/Documents/Coding-Projekte/newversioningmachine/node_modules/saxon-js'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./src/js/index.js 1:0-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js 4661:335-348
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/bastian/Documents/Coding-Projekte/newversioningmachine/node_modules/saxon-js'
 @ ./src/js/index.js 1:0-36
```

My question may be related to [SaxonJS unusable with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792808/saxonjs-unusable-with-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4669

I don't fully understand the issue, but the npm package for Saxon-JS is supported only on node.js and you're probably better off using the browser version.